# Play Framework on Heroku Compile Error when Adding a new Class

Tags: deployment, heroku, playframework

I am up and running on Heroku, everything's working great. I added a new class to my model, everything working fine on local. When i do a git push to Heroku i am getting the following error (note, i stopped my existing process and ran - `heroku run "play clean --%prod"` before doing the push):

Compilation error (In `/app/models/connectors/ContentConnectorIfc.java` around line 2589)
       The file `/app/models/connectors/ContentConnectorIfc.java` could not be compiled. Error raised is : `ContextVisionObstacleConnector cannot be resolved to a type`

```
   play.exceptions.CompilationException: ContextVisionObstacleConnector cannot be resolved to a type
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:516)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:278)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:412)
    at play.Play.preCompile(Play.java:566)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:291)
    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:158)
```

!     Failed to build Play! application
 !     Cleared Play! framework from cache
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Play! app

Answer (score 1):

It seems like something went wrong in your application's dependencies.
Have you checked your dependencies.yml? And make sure you run

```
play deps --sync
```

before you push onto heroku.

Comment: Ugh. I'm retarded. I forgot to do an add if the new resource to git, i just committed. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I keep forgetting that commit -a doesn't add the files, you have to do a separate add command. My bad. Nothing to do with heroku or play. Resources wasn't added to my push.